# WP 8: Image doesn't load immediately

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-8

I've got the following XAML:

```
<Image Width="100" Height="100" Source="{Binding ImageUrl}" CacheMode="BitmapCache" Grid.Column="0" />
```

ImageUrl is currently hardcoded to point at an URL.

What's troubling me, is that whenever I start the app from "scratch" (just started the emulator), the images won't load.

If I then rerun the app, the images show up just fine - probably because the image is now available in the cache.

So how do I get the image to show up the first time too ?

Comment: If you leave your application running, does it appear eventually?

Comment: maybe the size of the image is large....leave the emulator for about 10 seconds to see if its loads first time.

Comment: I've let the emulator stay at that view for around 15-20 seconds and nothing happens - however if I navigate to a different view and back, they'll appear. Also the image is rather small - about 24 kb.

Comment: How does it behave when you do not set `CacheMode="BitmapCache"`? Setting that property on an Image control does not seem to make much sense anyway.

Comment: It behaves exactly the same without the CacheMode attribute - if it doesn't make sense on an Image Control I've properly misunderstood what it does (I'll go read up on it)